# Sqlite: How to bind and insert date from C++?

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite, datetime, insert

Using C++ (Visual Studio) and sqlite.  How do I bind a date to a parameter?

```
sqlite3_stmt *statement;

const char *sql = 
    "INSERT INTO employees "
        "(full_name,"
        "date_started)" 
    " VALUES "
        "(@full_name,"
        "@date_started)";

sqlite3_prepare_v2(database_, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

int parameterIndex = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(statement, "@full_name");
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, parameterIndex, "John Smith", -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

parameterIndex = sqlite3_bind_parameter_index(statement, "@date_started");

// <??? what goes here ???>
// I want to include the local current time, so I want to know:
// 1. what's the best way to get local time in C++
// 2. and what goes here for the date binding

sqlite3_step(statement);

sqlite3_finalize(statement);
```

Note: I *don't* want to set the current time using sql (e.g, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I figured out.  It's working but I'm open to better methods.

```
time_t rawtime;
struct tm *currentTime;
time ( &rawtime );
currentTime = localtime ( &rawtime );

const int TIME_STRING_LENGTH = 20;
char buffer [TIME_STRING_LENGTH];

// SQLite expected date string format is "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" (there are others too)
strftime(buffer, TIME_STRING_LENGTH, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", currentTime);
sqlite3_bind_text(statement, parameterIndex, buffer, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Comment: Prefer to use `gmtime` instead of `localtime` as it is not sensitive to daylight saving time.

Comment: Ah I'm guessing that's probably why my compiler was giving me warning about using `localtime`.

Comment: Ultimately I prefer to have the datetime's as strings so I'm choosing this as the answer.  It's not really clear to me which is the best datetime format for a date column, but time will tell.

Answer (score 8):

There is no trick to it:

```
const char * sql =
    "INSERT INTO Employees(full_name, data_started) VALUES (?, ?)";
time_t time = 0x3DE43B0C;
sqlite3_bind_int64(statement, 2, time);
```

Here is the relevant part of the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

> ### 1.2 Date and Time Datatype
>
> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
>
> Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

Comment: I have defined my date_started column in my table as DATETIME, which has NUMERIC affinity (which apparently is mostly the same as REAL).  What happens when I use sqlite3_bind_text with a date string to insert a date?  Is it automatically converted into a REAL value (since that's the type of the column)?  Likewise with your integer example, does SQLite auto convert it to REAL?

Comment: It will be kept as an integer. If you try to put text in a column with NUMERIC affinity, SQLite will convert it only if it can be done losslessly and reversibly, otherwise it will keep it as text.

Comment: Well all my dates inserted via text binding are showing up in the database as text.  I just tried your method and indeed an integer shows up.  Not sure I like seeing an integer, that means I always have to call a function`datetime(date_started, 'unixepoch')` to see what the date is.  Do you know anything about the pros/cons of different types for storing dates in SQLite?

Comment: It is the usual tradeoff between storage space and query time. You could check whether calling `datetime` slows down your query; if not, then it would be better to store dates in the more compact integer form.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get the local time using the `localtime()` function.

```
/* localtime example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/ for detailed information and an example.

Comment: Well thank you for that, but my main question is how to bind this to an sqlite parameter.